# How do you add a javascript function to a webpage with multiple frames?

Tags: javascript, ios, frames

A webpage can have multiple frames each with its own document.  How do I add (and call) a javascript to one of the frames?  For instance,

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var script=frame1.document.createElement('script');"
 "script.type='text/javascript';"
 "script.text=\"function myFunc() {"
 "var test='a test';"
 "return test"
 "}\";"
 "frame1.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"];
```

Do I call the function like this

```
NSString *str=[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"frame1.document.myFunc();"];
```

Or this?

```
NSString *str=[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunc()"];
```

By the way, neither one seems to work.

Comment: It used to be `top.window.frames[0].document...`, however, `frames` are not supported by HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? (Replace *frameNumber* by an actual number):

```
NSString *script = @"window.frames[*frameNumber*].myFunc();"
NSString *str=[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

Comment: This didn't work.  Can anyone confirm that my script code doesn't have an error in it?